# Guess a buffer size and recall an api function or call it everytime twotimes to get exact buffer size

Tags: api, size, buffer

I want to retrieve the version information of msi-package(s)

What's the better way?

**First**: Guessing a buffer that is large enough and recall if it doesn't fit (ERROR_MORE_DATA)
*1 func call vs. 3 func calls and buffer can be bigger then needed*

**Second**: Call the api function to get the buffer size and then recall it to get the string with a (perfect) matching buffer size
*2 func calls every time with a perfect buffer size*

It's about (1 or 3) function call(s) vs. 2 function calls every time.

Is there any best practice for this "problem"?

I hope to get a generalized answer (assume calling function is really time consuming and/or buffer size can be very different (10 bytes to 200 megabyte) for further code writing. :-)

pseudo code:

First:

```
StringBuffer = 10 // (byte) guessing returned string will fit in 10 bytes  

result = MsiGetProductInfoW(
  product,
  INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING,
  VersionString,
  StringBuffer
); //maybe it fits in 10

if result = ERROR_MORE_DATA then //doesnt fit in 10 so recall to get the correct buffer size
begin
  MsiGetProductInfoW(
    product,
    INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING,
    nil,
    StringBuffer
  );

  Inc(StringBuffer); // cause null-terminated string

  // recall it with matching
  MsiGetProductInfoW(
    product,
    INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING,
    VersionString,
    StringBuffer
  );
end;
```

Second:

```
StringBuffer = 0;

// get buffer size
MsiGetProductInfoW(
  product,
  INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING,
  nil,
  StringBuffer
);

Inc(StringBuffer); // cause null-terminated string

// use it with the correct buffersize
MsiGetProductInfoW(
  product,
  INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING,
  VersionString,
  StringBuffer
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your First option, you can skip the second call, because even on the failing first call, the needed size should be stored in `StringBuffer`.

This makes the choice (1 or 2) vs. (always 2).  That should be clear enough.  Further, it shouldn't be hard to come up with a reasonable-sized buffer, that will pass 90+% of the time.